# What we do if we have more parameters to pass?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Explanations :

```
public void login(String userid,String pass)
    {
        driver.findElement(email).sendKeys(userid);
        driver.findElement(password).sendKeys(pass);
        driver.findElement(loginbutton).click();    
    }
```

If I want to add new user there are more than 2 almost 17 to 18 parameters l so it displays odd to add all in () bracket.

```
public void AddUser(String UserFName,String UserLName, UserPhone .. etc)
        {
            driver.findElement(Userfname).sendKeys(ufn);
            driver.findElement(UserLname).sendKeys(Uln);
            driver.findElement(phone).sendkeys(phone); .....    
        }
```

Please give suggestions .. I am stuck at this point .. if any want then I will explain in details.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use [Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) here.

Comment: What about using an UserDTO or UserBean with all the fields?

Comment: If you have to pass 18 parameters, there is something wrong with your design.

Comment: Just send one User object as parameter and set all values before calling method.

Comment: how about using `varargs`?

Comment: I am new in java and selenium so please if possible then explain with example .. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you encapsulate all these variables into a User object, and then just pass around User objects as parameters instead?

It seems kind of strange using Java if you're not going to create objects!

Answer (score 0):

Following dahui answer, an example could be:

```
User user = new User();

user.setUserFName(userfname);
user.setUserLName(userlname);
user.setPhone(phone);
...
```

Then in your method:

```
public void AddUser(User user)
    {
      //Change your code here
      driver.findElement(user).sendKeys(us);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First create an User Object , write setter and getter method for them and then populate the object as and when you want it and pass the user objects to AddUser method

```
public class User {

private String userFName = null ;
private String userLName = null;
:
:

public String getUserFName()
{
return userFname;

}

public void setUserFname(String name)
{
this.userFName = name;
}

// Do this for all attributes 

}
```

then in AddUser method

```
public void AddUser(User usr)
        {
            driver.findElement(Userfname).sendKeys(usr.getUserFName);
            driver.findElement(UserLname).sendKeys(usr.getUln);
            driver.findElement(phone).sendkeys(usr.getphone); 
            .....    
        }
```

learn about Page Factory pattern also , its very simple but very elegant and effective , you will need it if you are planning to work in java and selenium

Comment: Thanks vinod for replay, and also for suggestion about Page Factory.